# Using a Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to make an app that uses Google Maps Android API V2. So I searched the Internet about tutorials and I found a lot of useful tutorials. In the tutorials they said that, to use Google Maps Android API V2 I have to get a a Google Maps API key. Ok so far so good.

My question is

- Will this key work on multiple phones using my app ?
- Do I have to create an individual Google Maps API key for each new phone that downloads my app from the store ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will this key work on multiple phones using my app?

Yes, One Application with proper Map-Key can works on many devices. You dont need to create device wise map-key.

> Do I have to create an individual Google Maps API key for each new phone that downloads my app from the store?

No. One Key is enough.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to create just one API key for your app.

Comment: So it doesn't matter who downloads it and how many times it has been downloaded it will still work properly?

Comment: you have to make a release key before upload your app in the play store

Comment: @user3182266 , Right, it doesnt matter.